# Fetching data from Many to Many relationship (intermediate table)

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have set up a few models as follows:

**Product**

**Category**

Product and Category *share a many to many relationship* which makes a third table **product_categories**  which holds the product id and category id.

I want to display the list of products by its category.*emphasized text*I Now i have category id but i don't know how to fetch data from this intermediate table of M2M.

So please suggest me some way of doing this.

Thanks.

Edited

i have tried this stuff

my model

```
class Product():
    image = CharField(_("Image"), max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    style_idea = models.TextField(_("style idea"), blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField("Category", blank=True,
                                    verbose_name=_("Product categories"))
```

my **view**

```
if page.id == 11:
            value = Category.objects.all()
            value2 = Product.objects.all()
            value1 = ProductVariation.objects.all()
            return render_to_response('boutique.html',{'page':page,'productvariation':value1,'category':value,'products':value2} , context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

my **template**

```
{% regroup products by category as products_by_category %}
{% for c in products_by_category %}
{{c}}
{%endfor%}
```

this c prints all the products

Comment: have you looked in the docs at all? what have you tried?

Comment: @second I have edited my question please look at it

Comment: could you please post your models as well

Comment: what data are you trying to fetch from the intermediate table? It's handled by the framework by calls like `category.product_set.all()`

Comment: Say i have a categ_id = 10 then i want to fetch all the products which are under category 10.

Comment: just read the doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would do something like

```
category = Category.objects.get(pk=10)
products = category.product_set.all()  # note that this is a queryset
```